# Trying to Load Previous Quote to Cart Session

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to load a **quote** from a **previous order** into the cart in magento, though stuck here:

This code works the first time around, it adds the product to the cart.
However, if I refresh the page, the cart gets emptied out.

Can someone please advice what I'm doing wrong here?

**Magento 1.9**

```
$torder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($url_params['order_id']);
$tquoteId = $torder->getQuoteId();
$tquote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($tquoteId);

if ($tquote->getId()) {
   $tquote->setIsActive(1);
   Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->replaceQuote($tquote);
   Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not saved your cart. Try this

```
if ($tquote->getId()) {
   $tquote->setIsActive(1);
   $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session');
   $quote->replaceQuote($tquote);
   Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
   $quote->collectTotals()->save();
}
```

Comment: I did that, though getting the following error: Any idea how to correct this?

    Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::collectTotals

Edit - corrected this. Never Mind. Brain Freeze for a while.

Comment: Though there's the issue now - it doesn't persist across pages. If I go to the homepage or even the checkout page, it just shows up the old cart items whatever were there previously.

Comment: Use `getModel` instead of `getSingleton` in quote object. I have updated my answer. Please check